# How do I select a folder to save a file to in Jython using JFileChooser

Tags: java, jython, jfilechooser

I'm trying to use JFileChooser to select a folder to save a file to in Jython, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

The only example I've found so far was at this site: http://zetcode.com/gui/jythonswing/dialogs/, but its not really what I'm looking for.

I'm hoping to have just the file selection dialog open (the examples requires an awkward button press to activate the file dialog). I would also like to get the current directory of the selected folder instead of the filepath of a file.

Comment: https://github.com/smac89/src2pdf/blob/master/src/main/java/view/InteractionPanel.java#L158. You can see how the file chooser works in that method, and how to get the directory the user chose. Maybe this can help you

Comment: @smac89 it is helpful to know that the functionality is there, but I'm very unfamiliar with swing, so I'm still not really sure what I need to be doing. really unfortunate I cant just use tkinter!

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm not going to claim this is the cleanest solution in the world, but it does work and thats close enough for me.

```
from java.awt import BorderLayout
from javax.swing import JFileChooser, JFrame, JPanel 

class DropDown(JFrame):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DropDown, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):


        self.panel = JPanel()
        self.panel.setLayout(BorderLayout())

        choseFile = JFileChooser()

        choseFile.setDialogTitle('Select Export Location')
        choseFile.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY)

        ret = choseFile.showSaveDialog(self.panel)

        if ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
            if choseFile.getSelectedFile().isDirectory():
                self.file_name = str(choseFile.getSelectedFile())

    def get_file_name(self):
        return self.file_name
```